# Scala abstract class type with a Lower Type Bounds. I could not understand

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

The code  loos like this.
I can't figure out why the planType in this brackets .And I also write some tests to conquer it, but no value.

```
abstract class QueryPlan[PlanType <: QueryPlan[PlanType]] extends TreeNode[PlanType] {}
```

Comment: This is called **F-Bounded** Polymorphism. So `PlanType` is a type variable, but it can not be anything, it has to be something that extends `QueryPlan` but with itself, something like `final class MyPlan extends QueryPlan[MyPlan]`

Comment: If you are familiar with Java, it would be `abstract class QueryPlan<P extends QueryPlan<P>> extends TreeNode<P>` there.

Answer (score 0):

The writer of this `abstract class` wants the child classes to be only able to use `PlanType` which are of the type `QueryPlan[PlanType]` **or its subtypes.**

This is also termed Type-Narrowing in [scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/upper-type-bounds.html). The `QueryPlan[PlanType]` is the `upper-type bound` in this example.

So, the class `QueryPlan[PlanType <: QueryPlan[PlanType]]` cannot have all the `PlanType`s that are inherited from its parent `TreeNode[PlanType]`

In the example below, the type on left is `narrowest`, while `Any` on the right will be the `widest` type

```
QueryPlan[PlanType] <: TreeNode[PlanType] <: ParentPlanType <: Any
```

Comment: In my view , the `PlanType`  means strict. And I think  F-Bounded Polymorphism is more easy to understand.